# Azure Data Factory use two Integration Runtimes for failover

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory V2 with an Integration Runtime installed on the our internal cloud server and connected to our Java web platform API. This passes data one way into ADF on a scheduled trigger via a request to the IR API.

The Java web platform also has a DR solution at another site, which is a mirror build of the same servers and platforms. If I was to install another IR on this DR platform and link to ADF as a secondary IR. Is there a way for ADF to detect if the primary is down and auto failover to the secondary IR?

Thanks

Comment: I could install 2 nodes of the same IR onto the two machines. But what about if I only wanted one to work at the same time? E.g. there is not High Availability on the DB's so need one turned off until the auto copy is complete. Is there a way to block/pause one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you question "Is there a way for ADF to detect if the primary is down and auto failover to the secondary IR?", the answer is no, Data Factory doesn't have the failover feature. The shared integration runtime nodes don't affect each other.

For another question in the comment, the IR can't be stop/pause automatically, we must set it manually on the machine:
[image]

Comment: That is correct, we ended up putting a powershell script on the failover to stop/start the services and ran 2 nodes of the same IR. Thanks